# Assembly instruction to alter for spaceship movement (DEC to MOV)

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, opcode

I have permission to modify this executable.

A game called Emperor of the Fading Suns has spaceships in it. When you launch into orbit with a specific ship, said ship lose one movement point.
[Game\OllyDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JhIP.png)
`DEC BYTE PTR DS:[EAX+2F]` reduces movement points by one

I want to alter this so that you have 0 movement points left.

I have tried a lot of stuff, but the reality is that I simply don't have enough experience to understand what I need to overwrite (assemble) in order to achieve 0 movement point per takeoff. Changing out DEC with INC works.

My beginning strategy went to this: `MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX+2F], 0`
(I am a novice at assembly)

Longer list of code for context:
[image: Longer assembly image]

Thanks for the tip, I'm really excited about making this a function so I don't have words to describe how happy I am for anyone to tell me how to do this. If there is additional info required then I'll post a longer version and link to it.

Comment: Changing this to `MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX+2F], 0` is the right idea, but the new instruction is one byte longer than the old one.  So you'll have to shuffle code around, shorten the existing code or find a code cave for this.  And without you showing us any details about the code, it is impossible to give more specific advice.

Comment: If you show the whole function, I'm sure we could find a solution.

Comment: @prl
I've added a second image in the OP. I've sadly yet to perceive opportunities to add code or shuffle\shorten assembly code. I hope the image sheds some light

Comment: @XenoTrenium Thanks!  Next time, please do not post pictures of code if possible.  Instead, post the code as text.  I realise that doing so may be difficult for your specific situation (in which case a picture is ok), but please try to do text if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to observe that the instruction at 457dd0 and 457dd6 are the same and can be combined.

```
457dce  8b45e4    mov eax, [ebp-1c]
457dd1  7506      jnz 457dd9
457dd3  c6402f00  mov byte ptr [eax+2f], 0
457dd7  6690      nop
457dd9  ...
```

You should ensure that there are no jumps to 457dd0 or 457dd6.

Comment: Heh, yeah, debug builds certainly leave lots of room to shorten things by removing redundant instructions!

Comment: This works!
The single jump that referred to dd6 was already covered so this seems like a fully functioning alteration. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: @XenoTrenium: If an answer fully answers your question, you should "accept" it with the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Comment: You're right, done.

Thanks to everyone who helped, I've come a lot further thanks to your input!